# Trying to move express API code to controller file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, controller

I am missing something obvious here.

in my routes/api file this works fine (I get the expected users back from mongodb)

```
const User = require("../../database/models/User");
router.get("/getUsers", async(req, res) => {
  try {
   const users = await User.find();
   res.status(200).json(users)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
}
```

I am trying to move this code to a controllers file.

```
const getUsers  = require ('./../../controllers/users_controller');
router.get("/getUsers", getUsers);
```

I import the controllers file into routes/api

```
const User = require('../database/models/User');
module.exports = () => {
  getUsers = async(req, res) => {

    try {
      console.log ("getting users");
      const users = await User.find();
              
     // res.status(200).json(users);
     console.log("users:", users);
     res.status(200).json(users)
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }

  }
```

When I pull up the same endpoint that worked in the first example I get the error read ECONNRESET in PostMan.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try like this in controller

```
const User = require('../database/models/User');

  const getUsers = async(req, res ,next) => {
    try {
      console.log ("getting users");
      const users = await User.find();
              
     // res.status(200).json(users);
     console.log("users:", users);
     res.status(200).json(users)
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
  }

  exports.getUsers = getUsers;
```

in route file

```
const usersController  = require ('./../../controllers/users_controller');
router.get("/getUsers", usersController.getUsers);
```

if you have multiple functions in controller:

```
const User = require('../database/models/User');
 const getUsers = async(req, res ,next) => {
  //do somethings
  }
 const getUserById = async(req, res ,next) => {
  //do somethings
  }
  exports.getUsers = getUsers;
  exports.getUserById = getUserById;
```

in route file

```
const usersController  = require ('./../../controllers/users_controller');
router.get("/getUsers", usersController.getUsers);
router.get("/getUsers/:id", usersController.getUserById);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually had code similar to the last part (multiple functions in controller) but I was getting the same error that I am getting after putting in your example:  Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object].

Here is the entire controller file right now.

const User = require('../database/models/User');

const getUsers = async(req, res) => {

  try {
    console.log ("getting users");
    const users = await User.find();
   res.status(200).json(users)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
}

}

Comment: try the `res.status(200).json({users});` and show me the result again, in postman body you got [object, object]??

Comment: oh, sorry - I misspoke.  It is the compiler that gives me the error, not PostMan.  Same error with the updated code from your comment:  Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Comment: check the path of  `require ('./../../controllers/users_controller');` it's incorrect

Comment: Weird!  I added a second smaller function just to verify that it wasn't a problem with the require statement and now the original function is compiling and working.  Thanks again!!!!